# Using OWASP Top 10 for assigning vulnerability severity in a security assessment

Tags: appsec, risk-management, risk-analysis, vulnerability-assessment

In a research, I aim at prioritizing vulnerability patching for web applications. Since web application vulnerabilities do not have severity scores assigned like done for vulnerabilities (CVEs are assigned CVSS)  i thought of using [OWASP top 10 2017](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_2017_Project) as a measurement yard-stick. More specifically, I want to employ a scale of 1-10 for vulnerabilities such that vulnerabilities with `CWE(s)` within `A1` are  assigned `10` and `A6` are assigned `5`. Will this be fair/reasonable enough or are there better ways for doing something like this ?

**Update**: Just stumbled upon [CWSS](https://cwe.mitre.org/cwss/cwss_v1.0.1.html) and realized it is designed for scoring web applications using `CWE` categorization. For example 
2011 CWE/SANS Top 25 Most Dangerous Software Errors were scored using [prevalence scores](https://cwe.mitre.org/top25/). 
[image]

Does anyone know if something similar is available for top 10 2017 ?

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't want to calculate the CVSS score for each vulnerability?

Comment: @Neil I am considering calculation of CWSS rather than CVSS given these are web application vulnerabilities.

Comment: CWSS really isn't used. Have you tried to find a CWSS calculator? I've looked before and couldn't find one. A bad sign about it's use. While some question whether CVSS is useful for web apps, it is frequently used for the web. For example, see these [PHP vulnerabilities](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-74/PHP.html). I guess I don't feel strongly, but certainly lean towards the industry-standard CVSS v. the never-really-used CWSS.

Comment: Oh - one advantage to using CVSS is that you will help train your developers in using a common standard. There's not much value in them understanding CWSS.

Comment: @NeilSmithline I agree with you, I couldn't find much references with using CWSS. I'll probably go the CVSS route, just that I have no experience with assigning the scores myself especially as since these are web apps. Thanks for the php vulnerabilities link, I can learn from it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that using the ranking in the T10 as priority really makes sense. The T10 is ordered based on a combination of prevalence and risk. For an individual vulnerability, prevalence is irrelevant, all that matters is risk. Even for risk, the T10 makes lots of generalizations and, by necessity, cannot determine business risk for your company. From [Top 10-2017 Note About Risks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10-2017_Note_About_Risks):

> This rating does not take into account the actual impact on your business. Your organization will have to decide how much security risk from applications and APIs the organization is willing to accept given your culture, industry, and regulatory environment. The purpose of the OWASP Top 10 is not to do this risk analysis for you.

I don't think that anything will be as accurate as basing priorities off of the CVSS score for each vulnerability.

Comment: what do you think of using the OWASP Risk Rating Methodology (https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Risk_Rating_Methodology) since this methodology forms the basis for the OWASP top 10 ranking. According to this chart (https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10-2017_Details_About_Risk_Factors) the vulnerabilities are scored using the various risk factors except two : `Threat Agents` and `Business Impact`. I believe customized scores can be computed if these risk factors are provided considering the target environment.

Comment: The T10 rating methodology is seriously dumbed down to make it short and simple enough to fit in the T10. What's wrong with CVSS? @SyCode

Comment: The major concern is most web applications are not scored using CVSS. Therefore scoring has to be done by security analysts, this becomes subjective and prone to error. My aim is to score but not from the scratch, but rather use metrics that provide clear guidance... hence my earlier suggestion of using the OWASP Risk Rating methodology alongside with CWE Ids of the respective vulnerabilities.

Comment: Have you looked at a the CVSS calculator @SyCode? https://www.first.org/cvss/calculator/3.0 I think with a bit of training, you could get reasonable results from engineers. Security Champion programs where you train one dev in each team are good for this.

Comment: It sounds like what might work best for you is to just pre-rate the issue type. So say Code Injection and SQL injection are priority 1, XSS is priority 2, etc... Whatever makes sense. This won't be as accurate as CVSS, but it leaves nothing open to interpretation.

Comment: For example, on `T10 - A1` references four CWE-IDs `(CWE-77, CWE-89, CWE-564 and CWE-917)`.   `A1`  is scored ` 8.0`,  though the threat agent and business impact metrics are left out since these are environment specific. Assuming these are scored, the scores are then  effectively adapted to the target environment. By extension, other vulnerabilities could be assigned scores based on which category they fall into using `CWE Ids`  for guidance. A challenge might be those `CWE-ids` not on the list, and for these ones lower scores could be assigned.

Comment: Sure. That will definitely work @SyCode. And it is simpler than CVSS. It is also better than a static prioritization of CWEs. It will still require some training and/or strong documentation to enable dev teams to use it.